# Elasticsearch cluster health vs cat allocation IP address

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do `_cluster/health` I get following (abbr. for clarity):

```
"nodes": {
   "0KSzdqFERwaOyuqZ4oJwMA": {
      "name": "Index3",
      "transport_address": "inet[/172.16.120.113:9300]",
      "attributes": {}
   },
   "IkaQ9UOXRpqnvdnkQLXVAA": {
      "name": "Index4",
      "transport_address": "inet[/172.16.120.114:9300]",
      "attributes": {}
   }
}
```

Now when I add third node, `_cluster/health` look like this:

```
"nodes": {
   "0KSzdqFERwaOyuqZ4oJwMA": {
      "name": "Index3",
      "transport_address": "inet[/172.16.120.113:9300]",
      "attributes": {}
   },
   "IkaQ9UOXRpqnvdnkQLXVAA": {
      "name": "Index4",
      "transport_address": "inet[/172.16.120.114:9300]",
      "attributes": {}
   },
   "U_XMvuwNTDqspzYAJlEm4w": {
      "name": "Index5",
      "transport_address": "inet[/172.16.120.115:9300]",
      "attributes": {}
   }
}
```

But when I do `_cat/allocation` I see following:

```
27 42.3gb 17.6gb 59.9gb 70 INDEX3 172.16.120.113 Index3 
27 39.3gb 20.6gb 59.9gb 65 INDEX4 172.16.120.114 Index4
27 39.5gb 20.4gb 59.9gb 67 INDEX5 169.254.20.178 Index5
```

And under `_cat/shards` Index3 is trying to move some shards to Index5 node on that `169.254.20.178` address and is stuck there. `_cluster/health` shows that cluster is green, but shard reallocation never completes.

I tried setting network.host but issue persists:

```
network.host: 172.16.120.115
```

Can someone explain where/why/how this is happening? How/why is `_cat\allocation` picking up `169.254.20.178`?

Setup is running on Windows Server 2008R2 with elasticsearch 1.1.1.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is `ipconfig /all`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SOMEHOSTNAME
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : dfw.intensive.int
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : dfw.intensive.int
                                       intensive.int
                                       sat.intensive.int
                                       iad.intensive.int
                                       ord.intensive.int
                                       lon.intensive.int
                                       hkg.intensive.int
                                       syd.intensive.int

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 7A-2B-CB-33-9B-BB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::782b:cbff:fe33:9bbb%16(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.20.178(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 460991435
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-95-67-50-78-2B-CB-33-9B-BF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter PublicNetTeam:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : BASP Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-2B-CB-33-9B-BB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.120.219(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.120.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : >>MASKED<<
                                       >>MASKED<<
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter BackupNet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client) #33
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-2B-CB-33-9B-BF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.241.216.69(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Heartbeat2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client) #34
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-2B-CB-33-9B-C1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

And information from elasticsearch.log when node starts up. As you can see it is binding on `172.16.120.115`.

```
[2015-09-15 15:12:58,510][INFO ][node                     ] [Index5] version[1.1.1], pid[2436], build[f1585f0/2014-04-16T14:27:12Z]
[2015-09-15 15:12:58,510][INFO ][node                     ] [Index5] initializing ...
[2015-09-15 15:12:58,526][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Index5] loaded [], sites []
[2015-09-15 15:13:02,395][INFO ][node                     ] [Index5] initialized
[2015-09-15 15:13:02,395][INFO ][node                     ] [Index5] starting ...
[2015-09-15 15:13:03,362][INFO ][transport                ] [Index5] bound_address {inet[/172.16.120.115:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/172.16.120.115:9300]}
[2015-09-15 15:13:07,060][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Index5] detected_master [Index4][IkaQ9UOXRpqnvdnkQLXVAA][647264-INDEX4][inet[/172.16.120.114:9300]], added {[Index3][0KSzdqFERwaOyuqZ4oJwMA][INDEX3][inet[/172.16.120.113:9300]],[Index4][IkaQ9UOXRpqnvdnkQLXVAA][INDEX4][inet[/172.16.120.114:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Index4][IkaQ9UOXRpqnvdnkQLXVAA][INDEX4][inet[/172.16.120.114:9300]]])
[2015-09-15 15:13:07,278][INFO ][discovery                ] [Index5] elasticsearch/U_XMvuwNTDqspzYAJlEm4w
[2015-09-15 15:13:08,152][INFO ][http                     ] [Index5] bound_address {inet[/172.16.120.115:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/172.16.120.115:9200]}
[2015-09-15 15:13:08,152][INFO ][node                     ] [Index5] started
```

What is boggling is that I can issue requests on `http://172.16.120.115:9200` and I get responses back, but the module that does shard reallocation seems to be getting `local link` IP.

```
curl http://172.16.120.115:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
   "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
   "status": "green",
   "timed_out": false,
   "number_of_nodes": 3,
   "number_of_data_nodes": 3,
   "active_primary_shards": 27,
   "active_shards": 54,
   "relocating_shards": 2,
   "initializing_shards": 0,
   "unassigned_shards": 0
}

curl http://172.16.120.115:9200/_cat/shards
logindex_r210        1 r RELOCATING  240670 104.2mb 172.16.120.114 Index4 -> 169.254.20.178 Index5 
logindex_r210        1 p STARTED     240670 104.2mb 172.16.120.113 Index3                      
logindex_r210        2 p STARTED     240747 106.4mb 172.16.120.114 Index4                      
logindex_r210        2 r STARTED     240747 106.4mb 172.16.120.113 Index3                      
companyindex_r210    4 p STARTED     394869  52.6mb 172.16.120.114 Index4                      
companyindex_r210    4 r STARTED     394869  52.6mb 172.16.120.113 Index3                      
companyindex_r210    0 p STARTED     395000  62.6mb 172.16.120.114 Index4                      
companyindex_r210    0 r RELOCATING  395000  52.7mb 172.16.120.113 Index3 -> 169.254.20.178 Index5
```

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses in the 169.254.0.0 range are the standard "link local" block. As described in [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735), it is allocated for communication between hosts on a single link. Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration, such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.

So it looks like your node has 1) no static IP address configured and 2) couldn't get one from a DHCP server, so it makes up an IP address of its own in the 169.254 range so it can communicate on the network.

You might want to fix this in order for your shard allocation to proceed. The fact that your node couldn't get an IP address is most probably the reason why the relocation is stuck.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Val. I added additional information. Node is bound on the proper address and returns information etc., but module of elasticsearch that does shard rerouting/reallocation is getting `link local` IP.